# Big Omega with a plus/minus subscript

Tags: number-theory, discrete-mathematics, notation, asymptotics

I am reading an article that says $q(x)=\frac{M(x)}{\sqrt{x}}=\Omega_{\pm}\{{1}\}$, where M(x) is the Mertens function.  What is the difference between $\Omega_{\pm}$ and $\Omega$?

Comment: Without any context, this is quite difficult to answer.

Comment: The statement is:  It is known that $q(x)=\frac{M(x)}{\sqrt{x}}=\Omega_{\pm}\{{1}\}$ but it remains unknown whether q(x) is unbounded.

Comment: Is the notation $\Omega_\pm$ a standard asymptotic notation?  If so, what does it mean?

Comment: I got my answer already after looking at some other papers.

Comment: If you find the answer to your question, it's good practice to post an answer and accept it, both so the question doesn't stick around unanswered, and so others with the same question can find the answer. I have the same question and would be interested in your answer.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't been able to track down a source for this notation yet, but I came across it [here](https://www.maths.ed.ac.uk/%7Ecbarwick/papers/gamma-text.pdf) (1.1.1). There seems to be a small typo in the definition of $\Omega_-$, but it is easily corrected in context of the examples given in the margin. For the record, the correct definitions are:

Let $f:X \to \mathbb{C},g: X \to \mathbb{R}_{>0}$ , and $a \in X$. Then,

- $f(x) = \Omega (g(x))$ as $x \to a$ iff $\lim \sup_{x \to a} \frac{|f(x)|}{g(x)} > 0$.
- $f(x) = \Omega_+ (g(x))$ as $x \to a$ iff $\lim \sup_{x \to a} \frac{f(x)}{g(x)} > 0$.
- $f(x) = \Omega_- (g(x))$ as $x \to a$ iff $\lim \sup_{x \to a} \frac{-f(x)}{g(x)} > 0$.
- $f(x) = \Omega_{\pm} (g(x))$ as $x \to a$ iff $f(x) = \Omega_+(g(x))$ and $f(x) = \Omega_-(g(x))$ simultaneously as $x \to a$.